# Oracle's COLLECT function creates new collection data type with random name

Tags: oracle

Oracle'c COLLECT function triggers creation of a new collection type. 
Is there a way to disable this behavior ?

here is what is happening ...

check existing user types

```
select object_name from user_objects where object_type = 'TYPE'
no rows selected.
```

create user data type with collection VARRAY wrapper type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_T  
   AS OBJECT (C1 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), C2 VARCHAR2 (11 Byte));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ARRAY_TEST_T AS VARRAY(200) OF TEST_T;
```

check types  ...

```
select object_name from user_objects where object_type = 'TYPE'

OBJECT_NAME                                                                     
------------
TEST_T                                                                          
ARRAY_TEST_T 

2 rows selected.
```

now this query will trigger creation of a new collection type:

```
select cast(collect(TEST_T(c1,c2)) AS ARRAY_TEST_T) 
from (  select '1.1' as c1, '1.2' as c2 from dual ) ;
```

check types again ...

```
select object_name from user_objects where object_type = 'TYPE'
OBJECT_NAME                                                                     
-----------------------------
TEST_T                                                                          
SYSTP5Iel7MEkRT2osGnB/YcB4A==                                                   
ARRAY_TEST_T                                                                    

3 rows selected.
```

Oracle has created new collection type **"SYSTP5Iel7MEkRT2osGnB/YcB4A=="**  with following spec :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "SYSTPzGCo9gclT3WmlUX5SNtEPg==" AS TABLE OF TEST_T
```

Comment: I have the same behaviour on 10.2.0.3.0, don't know how/if you can disable this automatic type creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306

I think it will work when you define:

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ARRAY_TEST_T AS Table OF TEST_T;

So no varray(200) of ... but table of... .

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still think that Oracle will create temporary types even for "TABLE" definition.

Comment: Facing this problem on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production, even if I created a Type as table of varchar2 and then used CAST with COLLECT. Kind of lost.